# Why is $\mu\to e \gamma$ forbidden in the SM w/o neutrino masses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, standard-model, leptons

I have some questions about the next problem:

> The process µ → eγ does not
>   occur in the Standard Model in the absence of neutrino masses.
>
> a) The muon is identical to the electron except for its mass. What is
>   the Lagrangian density for electrons and muons coupled to electromagnetism?

Since the Lagrangian for electrons coupled to electromagnetism is
$$ L = - (1/4) F_{\mu \eta}F^{\mu \eta} + \bar{\psi}(i \gamma^{\mu}D_{\gamma}-m)\psi$$ where $D_{\mu} = \delta_{\mu} + ieA_{\mu}$ and $\psi$ is the electron spinor. I think the Lagrangian for electorns and muons whould just be 
$$ L = - (1/4) F_{\mu \eta}F^{\mu \eta} + \bar{\psi}(i \gamma^{\mu}D_{\gamma}-m)\psi + \bar{\phi}(i \gamma^{\mu}D_{\gamma}-M)\phi$$ for the muon spinor $\phi$ with mass M. Is this right or am I missing an interaction term between both fermions?

> b) What are the conserved charges due to the non-spacetime symmetries
>   in this theory, and their physical interpretation? Explain, based on symmetries, why the process µ → eγ is forbidden
>   in this theory.

I can only think on symmetries like $$ \psi, \phi \rightarrow e^{i\alpha}\psi, 
  e^{i\beta}\phi $$ Are there any others? I think I should get Lepton number and Lepton family from Noether's thoerem and conclude that lepton family (flavor) is not conserved for the process $\mu\to e\gamma$, which is why it is forbidden, is this right?

Comment: muon number conservation? One of the reasons muon number conservation was posited ( as law from data)

Comment: is there a symmetry related to EM that you've missed? are all of the symmetries global? or are there any local ones? why do you conclude lepton flavor is not conserved?

Comment: Remember, if you figure out the answers before anyone answers here, you are encouraged to answer your own question here.

Comment: I don't think there are any local symmetries. I conclude that Muon number is nos conserved and that's why this process is forbidden.

Comment: Is there a local symmetry associated with electromagnetism? Sorry, I think I misunderstood your comment about muon number conservation.

Comment: Also flavor changing neutral currents are not allowed(unless of course it was not a tree diagram).  Also photons can not promote decay unless if it is with the same particles. Like it can help particles lose energy or matter antimatter collisions result in photons(or Z bosons sometimes).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, in Standard Model Lagrangian, there are no vertex involving an electron, a muon and a photon at tree level: $\mathcal{L}_{SM} \not\supset \; \bar \psi \, \gamma^\mu A_\mu \, \phi $.

So, one should ask *why can neutrinos with mass allow $\mu \rightarrow e \gamma$ eventhough it is not allowed in tree level?*

In fact, muon can, in principle, decay into an electron and a photon if neutrinos oscillate because of having nonzero mass (which is the case). A muon decaying into a *virtual* muon neutrino and a *virtual* W boson can give you an electron if the muon neutrino oscillates to an electron neutrino to annihilate with the W boson. However this kind of decay is extremely rare to be observable.

Comment: The fisrt paragraph is difficult to understand as written. Do you mean to say that there is no vertex involving $\{e,\mu,\gamma\}$, so that the proposed process does not happen at tree level?

Comment: Yes. I clarified the sentence.